# Ping spikes on 5ghz/2.4ghz wi-fi only on one computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, ping

I have strange problem with Wi-Fi on my latop. I tried to use 5ghz and 2.5ghz - and it make no significant difference. When I ping my router it looks like this:

```
Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=65ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=167ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=175ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=88ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2381ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=3950ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=126ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 26, Received = 25, Lost = 1 (3% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 3950ms, Average = 280ms
```

The spike occurse very unregullar, sometimes I can send 50 or more pings without it, and sometimes it happend few times in half minute like you can see above.

Now some details:

- I ping my router so it is not problem with my ISP.
- It happend only on one from 3 tested laptops, two of them were on Win8.1, one on WinXP.
- The lagging one is on Win8.1.
- Turning off antivirus, system firewall and even pinging in windows safe mode didin't changed anthing.
- I updated wi-fi card driver (it's realtek 8821AE) and the error is not fixed.
- Pinging localhost works fine, no spikes here, so it seems that network card is good.
- On Wired connection on this laptop I have stable, low ping to router but because of it's standard location I need wi-fi connection.
- System is also updated.

The question is - how to fix this issue? I know that wired connection is always batter for low ping and I can accept 1-5ms ping which I have on Wi-FI on two other laptops. I just want the same stability level on the third.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I think, I fixed the issue by myself. In case of someone with similiar problems I will post here possible fix: 

**It is caused by bugged Windows action when scanning for avaible Wi-Fi networks in background**. To fix this random spikes you have to disable "Background Scan" using aplicaton like "WLAN Optimizer" or by modify system registry. It's still not prefect in my case but at least it prevent packet lost ("request timeout") and even if sometime spike apear it is relativly small like 150ms. Remember that you will not have possibility to scan for new Wi-Fi unless you undo the changes.